# How can I "wrap" a Linq2Sql data context in a webservice?

Tags: web-services, linq-to-sql

Relevants: Visual Studio 2010,
WCF WebServices,
Linq2Sql,
.Net 4.0

Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but I believe I have seen something similar to what I'm trying to do.

We have a Linq2Sql data context we are using to read/write to a database.  We'd like to expose a public API to the database for certain vendors.  I seem to recall a way to expose most of the data context functionality through a web service without creating wrappers for all the CRUD methods manually.  Anybody out there know how to do this?  I seem to remember seing the data context exposed through a web service with just a few lines of code.

We would also need to deny access to some methods, based on permissions, but can probably work through that ourselves.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of OData?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you saw or refer to... but WCF Data Services seem to be what you are after - check them out at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx

Answer (score 2):

@Yahia got me pointed in the right direction.  This article is nearly what I was looking for, but deals with ADO.Net Entity Data Models rather than LINQ data contexts.  Very nearly there...
[Data Access with ADO.Net Data Services](http://www.packtpub.com/article/data-access-with-ado-dot-net-data-services).

So, it turns out the answer is pretty simple.

1. Create a new ASP.Net web application.
2. Right-click the web application.
3. Add --> New Item --> WCF Data Service.
4. Modify the code to support your context:

   ```
   using System.Data.Services;
   using System.Data.Services.Common;

   namespace DelvingWare.Data.FilestreamServer.WebServices
   {
       public class WcfDataService1 : DataService<MyDataContext>
       {
           // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
           public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
           {
               // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
               // Examples:
               config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("MyEntitySet", EntitySetRights.ReadSingle);
               config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("MyEntitySet", ServiceOperationRights.ReadSingle);
               config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. Build --> Right Click Service --> View In Browser.  Voila!

Comment: If you like this answer, please updateo @Yahia's answer.  Never would have found this if not for him, and I just wanted to show more detail on the Linq2Sql specific solution for those who want it.